# Java socket programming call back

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have created a class library project "Communication" which is for communicating using UDP socket programming.

This communication will be invoked from application and made communication as always open and ready to accept using thread.

When ever data has to be sent, Since Application has the Communication object, its simple and easy to access.

But whenever a data is received, I want data to be sent to application.

refer pic below.

How to achieve this?, delegates?

[image: Query Img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an interface such as this:

```
interface Notifyable {
  void notify(DatagramPacket p);
}
```

and let your `Application` implement it.

Then give your `Communication` class the reference to `Application` and whenever you receive data, call the `notify` method.

Comment: Hey u understood my prob well, Im a newbie, can u pls tell, where to write interface? and where to implement class?

Comment: where to write interface? and where to implement class? and how to call

Answer (score 0):

UDP communication should work the same in both directions. There is no asymmetric client/server nor sender/receiver.  Your "Application" and "Communication" should work the same way.

Both can send messages and both can receive them in the same manner.

In other words, you should have written this code already on the listening side, you just need the same listening side on the "Application"

Comment: Application and Communication are single projects, Application is using Communication objects to send data over the network, Now what I need is to invoke a method which is in Appllication from communication

Comment: @ManojShenoy I assume you have some means of doing this on the "Communication" node?  What is stopping you from do the same on the "Application" node?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing fits perfectly into http protocol. In HTTP the server receives a request and sends a response to the client. So unless you have a specific requirement to use UDP the simplest servlet would give you a desired behavior - Server is always up and available and upon receiving an HTTP request your servlet would send a response. So, just read up how to get some Web Server or application  Server and create a servlet and you are all set. For simplicity I would recommend using Apache Tomcat as your server.